# WebAPI routing to specific method of controller by name

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

Here is what I have now: One route and all controllers so far confirm to it and work great. We want to keep those as is.

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DitatApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}"
```

Now we created new controller but need to route it differently. Below is a controller code and how those methods should be routed. How can I setup such route?

```
public class CarrierController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public object Get(string id, int? key, string direction)
    {
        return null;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public object Update()
    {
        return null;
    }

    [HttpDelete]
    public object Delete(int key)
    {
        return null;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public object GenerateRandomObject(int randomParam)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

1. `GET /api/carrier?id=<id>&key=<key>&direction=<direction>`
2. `POST /api/carrier`
3. `DELETE /api/carrier?key=<key>`
4. `GET /api/carrier/random?randomParam=<random>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WebApi v2 introduced the **Route Attributes**  and those can be used along with your Controller class and can facilitate the routing configuration.

For example:

```
 public class BookController : ApiController{
     //where author is a letter(a-Z) with a minimum of 5 character and 10 max.      
    [Route("html/{id}/{newAuthor:alpha:length(5,10)}")]
    public Book Get(int id, string newAuthor){
        return new Book() { Title = "SQL Server 2012 id= " + id, Author = "Adrian & " + newAuthor };
    }

   [Route("json/{id}/{newAuthor:alpha:length(5,10)}/{title}")]
   public Book Get(int id, string newAuthor, string title){
       return new Book() { Title = "SQL Server 2012 id= " + id, Author = "Adrian & " + newAuthor };
   }
...
```

However, please note that query parameters **?var1=1&var2=2** are not subject to evaluation to decide which API method will be used.

**WebApi** works based on reflection, so, this means that your curly braces {vars} must match the same name in your methods.

Therefore to match something like this `api/Products/Product/test` your template should look like this `"api/{controller}/{action}/{id}"` and your method needs to be declare like this:

```
[ActionName("Product")]
[HttpGet]
public object Product(string id){
   return id;
}
```

Where the parameter `string name` was replaced by `string id`.

Comment: What if I don't want {action} ? See my examples. I want separation by HTTP method and then one method with {action}